# Prize collecting CVRP in Google ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a problem that can be well modeled by the Prize Collecting CVRP with multiple vehicles and a single depot.  Each node visited has a benefit and there's an edge distance between each node.  Goal is to maximize the benefit of the visited nodes.  What's a little different from a typical CVRP with dropped nodes is that while there is no capacity constraint on the vehicles based upon their load, there is a max travel distance for each vehicle.

I've used ortools in Python for CVRP, but I don't know to approach this one. Any example code out there? My search yielded nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using penalties. (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties)

by setting the penalties to be an order of magnitude higher than the distances between nodes, the optimization process effectively becomes minimizing the penalty (which is similar to maximizing the profit when penalty(node) = profit(node))